# preg match not behaving as I remember

Tags: php, preg-match, behavior

this is absolutely bugging the hell out of me. I am usually bang on with PHP but this is frying my brain:

```
preg_match("/\/([0-9]*)\//i","http://url.com/folder/133302/",$s);
print_r($s);
```

outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => // [1] => )
```

I would expect it to match the number specified in the URL, im sure this used to work :s

if I add a letter it works fine (the letter x):

```
preg_match("/\/([0-9]*)x\//i","http://url.com/folder/133302x/",$s);
print_r($s);
```

outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => /133302x/ [1] => 133302 )
```

any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/\/([0-9]+)\//i","http://url.com/folder/133302/",$s);
```

If you say `*` ("zero or more times"), you also match `//`. `+` says "once or more" which is what you need.

Besides, you may want to use another separator, and drop the useless `i` modifier:

```
preg_match("#/([0-9]+)/#","http://url.com/folder/133302/",$s);
```